# Spring boot controller and service function for findById since find isnt working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

The code in service.java is something like this I want to use all basic CRUD operation.I am using a POJO which has id,name and description and I want to get a single topic using this..
and also why cant I use find ...its giving error...and in findById also I am not able to retrieve

```
@Autowired
TopicRepository topicRepository;
public Optional<Topic> getTopic(String id)
{ 
    //lambda expression
    //return topics.stream().filter(t->t.getId().equals(id)).findFirst().get();
    return topicRepository.findById(id);
}
```

I wanted to know how to write my controller class ?
currently my  controller function is like this

```
@RestController
public class TopicController {
    @Autowired 
    private TopicService topicService;
    //here a list of objects from the topic.java is returned and it
    //is converted to json automatically by spring

@RequestMapping("/topics/{id}")
    public Topic getTopic(@PathVariable String id)
    {
        return topicService.getTopic(id);
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Can you add repository code and error stack?

Answer (score 0):

You did not use any HTTP method to call the `getTopic` rest endpoint.

In REST, `GET` method is used whenever we want to **retrieve Resource**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/topics")
public class TopicController {
    @Autowired 
    private TopicService topicService;

    @GetMapping("/{id}") // GET HTTP method 
    public Topic getTopic(@PathVariable String id)
    {
        return topicService.getTopic(id);
    }
```

Comment: the default mapping for RequestMapping is get actually and its not at all a problem and I have sorted out this problem its just that i need to return in optional in controller and findById should be returned as optional

Answer (score 0):

Service Class function

```
public Optional<Topic> getTopic(String id)
    { 
        //lambda expression
        //return topics.stream().filter(t->t.getId().equals(id)).findFirst().get();
        return topicRepository.findById(id);
    }
```

and Controller function

```
@RequestMapping("/topics/{id}")
    public Optional<Topic> getTopic(@PathVariable String id)
    {
        return topicService.getTopic(id);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you are using Optional in **getTopic(String id)** method. So, you can not return the result of Optional directly from your controller. From your controller, you have to call **get()** method. Try Following code

```
@RequestMapping("/topics/{id}")
public Topic getTopic(@PathVariable String id)
{
    return topicService.getTopic(id).get();
}
```